# How to make a local indent in LaTex?

Tags: environments, indentation

When we are writing code, editors will usually make an local indent for a logic block (shift rightwards uniformly in this block), for example, if...else..., or for (...){ }

---

However, I also want to apply this convention to mathematics note-writing (thus, the pdf form produced, not the about the .tex file) , for a clearer logic frame (like, a proof below a statement). Better, such local indent environment should be able to nest itself any times whenever we want to make a further local indent inside it.

"\begin / \end {itemize}" has already been able to indent itself, but I just don't want an itemize here.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Does your question refer to indentation in the editing window (`tex` file), or on the paper document (i.e., `PDF`) produced by LaTeX?  If the `tex` file, then it is a function of the editor you are using.  If you are talking about a code listing in the output `PDF`, then it is a function of what environments you use to format the code.

Comment: Thank you! @StevenSegletes
Sorry, I didn't illustrate. It's about the pdf.

Comment: So, are you looking for something like "pseudo code"? https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=pseudo+code

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Well, I don't think so.    I'll put another way.
 I hope to define a simple environment that behaves very much like 'itemize' in terms of its local indent effect ( but of course I don't need to enumerate anything here).
Further, possibly, it able to change the text font also, so that the proof part  in such a math note looks very distinguishable from the usual statement.

Comment: There are various indenting environments, such as `quote` and `description`, in addition to `itemize` and `enumerate`.  With the `enumitem` package, you have great flexibility to structure the appearance and labels as you wish.  If none of these suit you, one can fudge indenting environments with `\leftskip` and `\rightskip`.  A picture of what you want would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need this, define your own special environment with the genral `\list` macro. Eg:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{myenv}
{\list{}{\rightmargin} \item\slshape\relax}{\endlist}
\begin{document}
\layout
\lipsum[1]
\begin{myenv}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myenv}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Here i have added `\slshape` as you said "able to change the text font also", but you obviously can adapt the formatting to your need.

Comment: Where can I find more information about `\list`?

Comment: You could e.g. have a look to https://tug.org/texinfohtml/latex2e.html#list